# Are these duplicate questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

This question was closed yesterday as off topic by five people (including me):

- [Can I omit the (c) when listing several consecutive nouns protected by copyright?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46492/can-i-omit-the-c-when-listing-several-consecutive-nouns-protected-by-copyright)

It was also downvoted five times and has no answers. (It's actually about `(R)`, not `(c)`.)

However, I was later surprised to find this question from less than a month ago:

- [Using “TM” for trademarked term - every time or just once?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/using-tm-for-trademarked-term-every-time-or-just-once)

This is still open with three upvotes and one downvote. It has three useful answers.

These are basically duplicate questions asking about repeating trademark symbols -- one reviewing a technical document, the other writing a press release. The answers from the second would help the first question.

Two questions:

- Is this sort of question off-topic?
- Is there any value in re-moderating the first as a duplicate of the second?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the questions on-topic, in the same way questions about the usage of other particular characters, or punctuation are. The questions are asked because a real problem (Should I write the trademark symbol every time, or is it enough I write it the first time I use the name of the company?), and they are different (for example) from the following question:

> I saw that my friend wrote "Hello,, my friend. How are you?" Should I use the double comma after *hello* every time I greet somebody in my email?

There is no need to have a question for *™*, *©*, and *®* (or *TM*, *(c)*, and *(r)*) because the answer is the same in all the cases. Who answers will not report that *™* can be used the first two times you make a reference to a company name, and *©* can be used only the first time. The symbols are different, but they are all used to report the legal status of something.
The existing question should be made more generic, without to invalidate the existing answers.

Comment: Yes, I agree (although © is a bit different to ™/®). What about the re-moderating bit?

Comment: After making the other question more generic, to include all the three symbols, we can consider closing the latter question as duplicate. For sure we don't want three different questions for each of the symbols.